# Java while loop for false

Tags: java, while-loop

I created a while loop which i want to stop when it becomes true

so i put:

```
while(!vending1.cansEmpty()) {
    vending1.clickCan();
    count++; 
}
```

now it has been set so that the vending machine has 10 cans inside 
and every time you call the method clickCan() it minus's 1 can,
but the while loop doesn't end when it the machine is empty (method becomes true), it just goes on infinitly
I am not sure why though

Comment: Show us `cansEmpty` and `clickCan` methods.

Comment: Look at your implementation of vending1. Obviously either clickCan() is never setting the field that cansEmpty() is testing, or that test is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VendingMachine(){
    private Integer cans;

    public VendingMachine(int numCans) {
        this.cans = numCans
    }

    public void clickCan() {
        cans--;
    }
    public boolean cansEmpty() {
        if (cans <= 0) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I think you just need to make sure that your cans empty function returns a boolean.